# Cannot restart docker container, logs contain no message

Tags: docker, containers

I'm new to docker, trying to feel my way around. I successfully set up and ran a docker container for 'taskserver' using this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/connectical/taskd/

I stopped the container but now I can't seem to restart it. It just immediately shuts down with no error message. I checked the logs and there are no new error messages, just the same messages from days ago when it was first started.

I'm not sure what else to try or how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: provide the command you used to restart the container

Comment: I tried both `docker start taskd` and `docker restart taskd`

Comment: Oh, and I also tried `start` with `-a` and `-i` switches.

Comment: Try `docker container restart taskd`

Comment: Can you run "docker ps -a" and post the result? Also "docker logs taskd" if it returns anything.

Comment: Yeah, it just shows the container is dead/not running. I'm closing the question. Fortunately, the the user files and security certificates I needed were shared with host machine. So I just downloaded a different taskd image and just moved the necessary files and used them with the new image. So I'm back on track. As best I can tell, once a process dies on a container, it's kaput. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is because the poster does not understand how Docker is expected to work.